# View can not find model class that is in another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two project in my solution. One of my project is a class library that I want to use as models while other one is mvc 4 web application project. Now when I send my model to my partial view from my controller my view does not render and gives the error that it could not find the class and the assembly containing the class is missing however i have added the assembly reference of my class library to the mvc project.

I need to ask that is it necessary in MVC project to have models in the same project? or I am doing something wrong

```
  @using TransactionManagment.Entities;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "D&C | User Admin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageLTE.cshtml";
}



@{
    var usr = (AppUser)ViewBag.User;
    var usrRights = usr.AppUserRights.AllUserPossibleRights;
}



<style>
    .mytabs {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: cadetblue;
    }
</style>


<script>
    function IsSuperUser() {

        if (document.getElementById('chkSuperUser').checked) {
            document.getElementById('tab_user_rights').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('tab_user_rights').style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }
</script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Custom Tabs -->
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="mytabs active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Users</a></li>
                <li class="mytabs" id="tab_user_rights"><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">User Rights</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane  active" id="tab_1">
                    <div class="">

                        <!-- form start -->
                        <form role="form">


                            <div class="box-body">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Select</label>
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option>New User</option>
                                        <option>option 2</option>
                                        <option>option 3</option>
                                        <option>option 4</option>
                                        <option>option 5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Designation</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDesignation" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtDateofBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmailAdd" placeholder="useremail@domain.com">
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Picture</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="txtPicture">

                                </div>

                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkSuperUser" onchange="IsSuperUser();"> Super User
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                    @foreach (var upr in usrRights)
                    {
                        foreach (var right in upr.Actions)
                        {
                            <label class="">
                                <div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue checked" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
                                    <input id="@{'.'+right}" type="checkbox" class="minimal" checked="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
                                </div> 
                            </label>
                        }

                    }
                    <h4>@{usr.UserName}</h4>
                </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->

                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_addUser">Save User</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        </div><!-- nav-tabs-custom -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
namespace TransactionManagmentWeb.Controllers
{
    public class UserAdministrationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /UserAdministration/

        public ActionResult UserAdministrationHome()
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser {AppUserRights = new AppUserRights()};
            return PartialView(user);
        }



    }
}
```

Error

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TransactionManagment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 1:  
Line 2:  @using TransactionManagment.Entities;
Line 3:  
Line 4:
```

Comment: You provide the code of the view?

Comment: And the exact error?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your model classes in another project? right

Comment: Correct, there is nothing wrong with that.  You need to add a reference from your MVC project to the project that contains your domain objects.

Comment: Have you tried giving the full namespace to the model in your view? For example `@model ClassLibrary.Models.MyModel`?

Comment: Show your view and the error.

Comment: Just see whether you are using a Strongly typed view or not

Answer (score -1):

You might need to add in your view markup

```
@using theothernamespace.Models
```

Comment: You might want to refrain from guessing in answers until you have enough reputation to post comments, so you can ask OP to show his view declaration, [which I already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697501/view-can-not-find-model-class-that-is-in-another-project#comment47531441_29697501).